# Projections from flag varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing

Let $K$ be a field and $k<n$. Denote by $G(k,n)$ the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional vecors subspaces of $K^n$. I'm trying to check that the projection map

$$G(k+1,n)\times G(k,n)\longrightarrow G(k,n)$$ is open.

I need this in order to check that the projection map from the flag variety $\mathcal{F\ell}(K^n;k,k+1)\longrightarrow G(k,n)$ is open.

Answer (score 3):

Flat morphisms locally of finite presentation are universally open (EGA IV2, Théorème 2.4.6), and thus your morphism is open.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a more direct proof?

Comment: This is pretty direct? It's basically just an application of Going Down, see for example https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00I1